# Regex token find and replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

Please could someone help me with writing a regex expression to replace 0044 token which will be at the start of the string with a 0. Please note that I do not want to replace all 0044 tokens with 0, only those that appear at the start of the string.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

In perl:

```
s/^0044/0/;
```

The `^` means that the match will only happen at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use regex its already answered above. i.e

Find What: `^0044`

Replace With: `0`

But here is a crude way to do it:

Press ALT, then select all the '`044`'s vertically using mouse and delete them. Keep ALT pressed while making the selection.

Answer (score 0):

Then why you dont put an space at the begining in the search and replace boxes, i mean:

```
Search: " 0044"
Replace " 0"
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The ^ works in notepad++ to match the beginning of the line.